# Getting a Text between two texts

Tags: c#, string

I'm trying to get a text that is placed between two word.

Project Name - **this is the text I want to get**, Contact Name -

how can I get exactly the Project Name without the first text and the last?

I Tried this code but it takes the Contact Name content too:

```
int Place1 = SecondText.IndexOf("Project Name");
int Place2 = SecondText.IndexOf("Contact Name");
Name = SecondText.Substring(Place1, Place2);
NameTB.Text = Name;
```

I have created a Cleaner function which deletes the words Project Name and Contact Name
But the contact  name stays in my string.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: you are best using Regex for this. Regex is designed for pattern matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put it like that:

```
  String SecondText = "Project Name - this is the text I want to get, Contact Name -";

  // Pay attention to + + "Project Name".Length; and - Place1
  int Place1 = SecondText.IndexOf("Project Name") + "Project Name".Length;
  int Place2 = SecondText.IndexOf("Contact Name") - Place1;
  Name = SecondText.Substring(Place1, Place2);
```

Comment: Thanks Dimitry, works great. even this one works: Name = SecondText.Substring(Place1, Place2 - Place1);

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
string SecondText = "Project Name - this is the text I want to get, Contact Name";
string result = SecondText.Replace("Project Name - ","");
int Place2 = result.IndexOf(", Contact Name");
string Name = result.Substring(0, Place2);
```

i hope this works for you